# Load dataset from modified csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a data file where the data is stored like :

```
key1:0.2164  key2:0.321  key3:0.1231
key1:0.3216  key2:0.149  key3:0.7894
...
```

So basically, column names are written as some kind of keys. Rows are delimited by new lines in the text file. There is no coma.
I would like to turn it into a proper dataframe where `columns=[key1,key2,key3]`

Obviously using `pd.read_csv(...,sep=':')` is not enough as I end up with values like `key1:0.1231` in each cell, where it should have been `0.1231`.

I am not sure if I should use a special regular expression as delimiter or if I should use another method to load the file (as it is not a real .csv)

Answer (score 1):

It's often more efficient to perform your manipulation before the data is in your dataframe. Here's an example using the `csv` module:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from io import StringIO

x = StringIO("""key1:0.2164 key2:0.321 key3:0.1231 
key1:0.3216 key2:0.149 key3:0.7894 """)

# replace x with 'file.csv'
with x as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=' ')
    df = pd.DataFrame([dict(i.split(':') for i in filter(None, row)) for row in reader],
                      dtype=float)
```

Result:

```
     key1   key2    key3
0  0.2164  0.321  0.1231
1  0.3216  0.149  0.7894
```

The logic works because the `pd.DataFrame` constructor accepts a list of dictionaries as an input.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will try that, just wanted to be sure there were no easy way to load this special data format I would not be aware of ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use converters to read the file. Here's how:

```
# read the columns names by loading one line and inferring the names from it
columns = pd.read_csv("filename", nrows=1, header=None, 
                      sep="\s+").values.tolist()[0]
columns = [c.split(":")[0] for c in columns]

# prepare the converters 
converters = {idx: lambda x: x.split(":")[1] for idx, _ in enumerate(columns)}

# read the whole file
df = pd.read_csv("filename", header=None, names=columns, sep="\s+", 
                 converters=converters)
```

---

#### output:

```
     key1   key2    key3
0  0.2164  0.321  0.1231
1  0.3216  0.149  0.7894
```

You can find more information about converters in the documentation of [pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: +1 for the converter, I have read the doc of pd.read_csv a couple of times but I never paid attention to the converter argument, great tip here !

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do it:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename',sep='\s+', names=['key1','key2','key3'])
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].str.split(':').str[1].astype(float)
```